# Can a symmetric matrix be computed using matrix-vector operation while maintaining least number of flops?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Consider A an nxn matrix. its not a special matrix and in the worst case all of its entries are non-zero. I am looking for a way to compute AA^T using matrix-vector operation. The total number of flops are (2n-1)*(n(n+1))/2 because all I have to do for a symmetric matrix like C=AA^T is to compute the diagonal entires which are C(i,i)=A(i,:)^T * A(i,:). What I want now is to compute the lower triangular part and then when I am done I just say that the upper triangular part is the same as the lower triangular part. The problem is can I do it in matrix-vector multiplication or will it force me to perform unnecessary multiplication (like multiplying elements in the upper part)? It is clear that a scalar computation would work but I am interested to know if a matrix-vector computation would work or not.

Comment: You could compute only the lower part, but note that finding an implementation more efficient than MATLAB's inbuilt matrix operations its going to be hard, as MATLAB itself does not just do the matrix multiplication as learned in algebra books, its uses quite efficient algorithms in conjunction with multi-threading.

Comment: Hello, I agree with you MATLAB indeed has some powerful optimized built in function but to compute the lower part only could it be done using a matrix vector operation or am I forced to only do it by taking j+1th column of A and multiply it by jth column of A? The latter is a vector-vector operation @Ander Biguri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB is already smart enough to do this for you. When MATLAB encounters an expression like A*A.', it will recognize that the two operands are the same and will call a symmetric BLAS library function in the background to do the calculation. This symmetric function does exactly what you want ... only does about 1/2 the operations and generates an exact symmetric result.